# Control on textboxes for a barcode application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wrote this piece of code where I want to control the input into a textbox with a barcode reader:

```
private void textBox3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.KeyCode != Keys.P && e.KeyCode != Keys.V && e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter && e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong value!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text.Remove(textBox3.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
        textBox3.Focus();
        textBox3.SelectionStart = textBox3.Text.Length;
        textBox3.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }


    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
        textBox3.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        textBox3.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
    }
}
```

In this textbox i want just the letter "P" or "V" and until i was testing this with a keyboard everything was fine.
Today I connected the barcode reader and now when i scan the "P" or "V" barcode, it gives me the error.

Should I use another textbox event? What's wrong with this?
Any help is welcome thanks.

WORKING VERSION:

private void textBox3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (e.KeyCode != Keys.P && e.KeyCode != Keys.V)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong value!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text.Remove(textBox3.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
            textBox3.Focus();
            textBox3.SelectionStart = textBox3.Text.Length;
            textBox3.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }               

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
            textBox3.AppendText("v");
            textBox3.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            textBox3.ReadOnly = true;
            textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.P)
         {                
             textBox1.Focus();
            textBox3.AppendText("p");   
             textBox3.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
             textBox3.ReadOnly = true;
             textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
         } 
    }
```

Comment: `it gives me the error.` => which error?

Comment: the messagebox one in code, "Wrong value!", like that is not the right letter

Comment: Apparently the barcode scanner is entering something other than those `KeyCode`s...

Comment: It's not entering other input, I tried it in Word and it's just the letter

Comment: Use a debugger, check the value of `e`, it's properties and put them in the question using the [edit] link

Comment: Note that your code would throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if `textBox3.Text` doesn't contain `Environment.NewLine`. You should store `textBox3.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine)` in an `int` variable and check if it's `>= 0` before you use `textBox3.Text.Remove(index)`.

Comment: Barcode scanners can act in strange ways when emulating keyboards. Are you sure the Scanner doesn't add some delimiters or padding characters? Also does the barcode scanner only supply a single key or does it supply you multiple?

Comment: it does supply also multiple, and trying on a text editor it doesnt add other delimiters or anything else

Comment: I managed to get it working like this fyi guys. (in the question)